# UINavigationController disappears when I switch to a different tab while UISearchController is visible

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchcontroller

In my app I have a `UITabBarController` with several `UINavigationController`'s. I am trying to add a search feature like in Apple's Music app, in which a search icon appears in every `UIViewController`'s `navigatonItem`. When this icon is tapped, a `UISearchController` is presented.

The problem I am facing is that if I present the `UISearchController` and switch to a different tab (before typing anything in the `UISearchController`'s `searchBar`), when I come back to that tab the `UINavigationController` is not visible anymore. Even if I cancel the search, the `UISearchController` is dismissed but I cannot see my original `UINavigationController`. If I do type something into the search bar before switching to a different bar and back, the search results remain always visible but when I dismiss the `UISearchController` my `UINavigationController` does not show up. I can only see the `UITabBarController`'s `tabBar` and everything else completely white.

However, if once the `UISearchController` has been dismissed, if I go to another tab and then back to the original one, the `UINavigationController` appears again.

Here's the code for my `UIViewController` subclass:

```
let searchResultsController = SearchResultsController()
var searchController: UISearchController!
var searchButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: Selector("showSearch:"))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
}

func showSearch(sender: AnyObject? = nil) {
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675961/uisearchcontroller-makes-the-controller-black?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISearchController makes the controller black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675961/uisearchcontroller-makes-the-controller-black)