# UISearchController makes content of the UITableView black

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem with the UISearchController in combination with UITabBarController. I have 3 tabs. In every tab, I have an UITableViewController with a search bar from UISearchController set as header view of the table view as follows.

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(searchController.searchBar.frame))
```

If I start searching and switch to the other tab without canceling the search and then return back to previous tab, the content of the UITableView become black. I have read multiple postings such as [UISearchController makes the controller black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675961/uisearchcontroller-makes-the-controller-black) or [UISearchController causes black screen Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291347/uisearchcontroller-causes-black-screen-swift-2-0). But these solutions do not work for me. If I am setting

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

then the problem first occur. If I omit this line then the content of the table view are not becomming black but the search bar stay activated in a searching state on the next tab. I also tried setting searchResultsController to another UITableViewController but it does not solve the problem too.

Comment: Have you tried programatically cancelling the search when user moves to another tab?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem,fixed by just adding the following line in `viewDidDisappear`

```
    self.searchController.active = false
```

> Usually, you get the value of this property to determine whether the search results are displayed. However, you can set this property to true to force the search interface to appear, even if the user has not taps in the search field.
>
> The default value of this property is false.

- From the above description it clearly says the default value is`false` if user interacts with `searchController` it switches to true.
- In our case issue occurs only if we switch tab's when the `UISearchController` is **active**.So we need to simply deactivate programatically while switching to other VC.

Comment: I am using this solution as a workaround too. But it has two drawbacks. First, if user clicks on the cell and then return back, the search results are reseted. Second, the animation duration of the search bar deactivation is different from swithing tabs. So if tab is switched, the search bar is still visible for a moment.

Comment: if you have no problem with `UISearchBar` go for it. It won't cause this kind of probs.